# How to avoid duplicate entries in .bash_history

Tags: bash, history

The same command is listed in my history again and again. How can I avoid this? I know it's possible via `HISTCONTROL` but I haven't found the right way.

Comment: I created a related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205520/history-list-without-timestamp-and-unique-the-results. Dups in the history is useful to see the context of a command. What you want to omit dups sometimes when you print the history.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> > A colon-separated list of values controlling how commands  are  saved  on
> >     the  history  list.   If  the  list of values includes `ignorespace`, lines
> >     which begin with a space character are not saved in the history list.   A
> >     value  of  `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to
> >     not be saved.  A value of `ignoreboth` is  shorthand  for  `ignorespace`  and
> >     `ignoredups`.   A value of `erasedups` causes all previous lines matching the
> >     current line to be removed from the history  list  before  that  line  is
> >     saved.   Any  value  not in the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is
> >     unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines  read  by  the  shell
> >     parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.
> >     The second and subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are  not
> >     tested,  and are added to the history regardless of the value of HISTCONTROL.

So put the following line in your `~/.bashrc`:

`export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups`

Comment: Do you want me to add HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth in the bottom of ~/.bashrc?

Comment: @karthick It doesn't matter where you put it, the bottom is fine though.

Comment: On my installation of Ubuntu 12.04 I had to make this modification in `~/.bash_login` Most of the time it would work if .bashrc is modified but that's not the case _all_ the time.

Comment: Don't forget to run these after you update your bash profile/rc files - `source ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 33):

Stick this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

You could instead use `ignoreboth`. This it shorthand for both `ignorespaces` (commands starting with spaces) and `ignoredups` (duplicates).

I prefer `ignoredups` on its own as I find the default behaviour of ignoring commands with spaces at the front quite annoying when I copy a command off a website and it doesn't get saved because I accidentally copied in a space too.... But to each their own.

Comment: Still duplicates exist..What may be the problem??http://imgur.com/fXeLQ.png

Comment: @karthick87 quoted from another answer: *A value of `ignoredups` causes lines matching the previous history entry to not be saved*. It only removes consecutive identical lines.

Answer (score 17):

Putting this in `~/.bashrc` will apply @alvin's solution across different sessions as wlell

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
shopt -s histappend
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Source: [Linux: Bash history: “ignoredups” and “erasedups” setting conflict with common history across sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18443/1566)

Comment: Why does his use `export HISTCONTROL` and yours doesn't? What's the difference? It's working for me without export, I'm just curious

Comment: Good question! I would also like to know the answer.
In general `export` makes the variable available to sub-processes.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158091/552621
In the case of `HISTCONTROL`, `PROMPT_COMMAND`, etc, these variables are used by the shell itself so maybe exporting them (to children processes) is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

To do this, you can use this command:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

```
export HISTCONTROL=erasedups
```

Answer (score 1):

To uniqely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```