# History list without timestamp in TTY terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, tty

I am running only Linux on a Mac computer. I am working on the TTY terminal only as I have not installed GUI yet. Right now, `history` gives me this:

```
$ history
    1  2016-10-05 00:25:36 grape instance status
    2  2016-10-05 00:26:00 history
    3  2016-10-05 00:27:10 history | more
    4  2016-10-05 00:44:56 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//' | uniq | grep -i "heroku"
    5  2016-10-05 00:45:36 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//' | uniq
    6  2016-10-05 00:49:29 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//'
    7  2016-10-05 00:51:32 history | cut -d " " -f7-1000 |
    8  2016-10-05 00:51:36 history | cut -d " " -f7-1000
    9  2016-10-05 00:56:54 history
```

I want to get rid of the timestamps and index number. I want just the commands. As you can see from the history, I tried solution of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205520/history-list-without-timestamp-and-unique-the-results): `history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//' | uniq | grep -i "heroku"`, but it does not seem to work on TTY terminal. It removes the index numbers, but the timestamp is still there. Output is as below (I omitted the  `uniq` and `grep` command as i don't need them):

```
$ history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//'
2016-10-05 00:25:36 grape instance status
2016-10-05 00:26:00 history
2016-10-05 00:27:10 history | more
2016-10-05 00:44:56 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//' | uniq | grep -i "heroku"
2016-10-05 00:45:36 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//' | uniq
2016-10-05 00:49:29 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//'
2016-10-05 00:51:32 history | cut -d " " -f7-1000 |
2016-10-05 00:51:36 history | cut -d " " -f7-1000
2016-10-05 00:56:54 history
2016-10-05 00:59:04 history | sed 's/.[ ]*.[0-9]*.[ ]*//'
```

I even tried running `history | cut -d " " -f7-1000 | sort` (from the comments in the linked question) but it does not remove the timestamps either.

I also tried running first solution from the link: `HISTTIMEFORMAT ="";`, but I get an error saying

> HISTTIMEFORMAT: command not found

Is it possible to get history without timestamps in TTY?

**EDIT:**
The solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205520/history-list-without-timestamp-and-unique-the-results) did not work for me initially because of a single space. (Given solution was `HISTTIMEFORMAT ="";` but the space had to be removed to make it work. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked this duplicate question.

Comment: Try `HISTTIMEFORMAT=` or `HISTTIMEFORMAT=""` (note: no space allowed between the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` and the `=` sign)

Comment: @steeldriver Hey, that worked! Can you post it as answer so I can tick it?

Comment: IMHO it really *is* a duplicate of the question you linked - although the answers there could use some edits

Comment: Please close this question as it has been answered. Also, this is a duplicate due to the same solution being given in the question you linked.

Comment: The problem isn't that you're using TTY - the answers to the other question just do not work. There you are only asking `sed` to match one set of numbers... For what you have there you could probably do something like `sed 's/^.*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\s//'` but obviously unsetting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` is better...