# No duplicated lines in bash history

Tags: bash, history

Supposedly, adding export `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` to `.bashrc` would do the trick, but what I see in practice is there still exists duplicated lines in my `.bash_history` file.

You can see my `.bashrc` below.

```
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
export HISTSIZE=100000 
export HISTIGNORE="ls*:rm*:cd*:CD*:ps*:exit*:reset*:clear*:synaptic*:mkdir*:cat*"
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
shopt -s histappend
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Does anybody know why I'm still getting duplicated lines?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15926/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entries-in-bash-history

Comment: I saw that question, but it does not seems to be the same since I'm already doing what it suggests

Comment: @Psicofrenia It is `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups`, or you write `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` that's incorrect.

Comment: Sorry but ... `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` and `export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups` are 2 diff. things

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, yes, exactly!

Comment: I changed to export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups and it still duplicating :(

Comment: `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` ignores only duplicate **consecutive** lines. You'll still get duplicate non-consecutive lines. Is that your problem?

Comment: Ah, maybe that's the problem. What I want is to NEVER have the same line twice in .bash_history, being consecutive or note. That means I can use only export HISTCONTROL=erasedups ?

Comment: From `man bash`: "A value of **erasedups** causes all previous lines matching the current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved." Did you test erasedups?

Answer (score 4):

HISTCONTROL only affects new hist lines.
What I think the author what is a way to edit the existing hist file.

`nl ~/.bash_history | sort -k 2 | uniq -f 1 | sort -n | cut -f 2 > temp_file`
followed by
`temp_file > ~/.bash_history`

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48713/how-can-i-remove-duplicates-in-my-bash-history-preserving-order) should preserve line order, while removing dups from the existing hist file.
May leave behind ghost time-stamps, if you have turned on time-stamps.
If you have that issue, comment, and I'll whip up a second clean up for those.

Comment: Great one-liners! Thanks. In my case, "temp_file > ~/.bash_history" didn't work, but "cat temp_file > ~/.bash_history". Also, you forgot a last "rm temp_file" :)

Answer (score 0):

"erasedups" should do the trick, did you `source .bashrc` after your change?

Can you please `echo $HISTCONTROL` and tell us the output? Also: be sure you actually want to do that on .bashrc and not in .bash_profile instead...

Basically, what I'm suspecting is that you simply don't have HISTCONTROL on your environment.

Comment: I changed to export HISTCONTROL=erasedups, opened a new tab, and used an inexistent command kaka. Cat the .bash_history before kaka was kaka kaka kaka, since I tried it 3 times before the change, after it became kaka kaka kaka kada

Comment: Btw, if I echo HISTCONTROL I get erasedups