# Tmux History not preserved

Tags: bash, tmux

I am facing an issue in which the commands that I run inside the tmux terminal are not found when I exit that tmux session. Can, anyone please help?

`tmux` - using this command to run tmux session

`echo "Hello"` - using this command in tmux session

`history` - In this case `echo "Hello"` command is present.

`exit` - using this to exit the tmux session

`history` - running this command after exiting from tmux session

After running this I am not able to get `echo "Hello"` command that I used in tmux session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exit the terminal and restart it. Now, `history` will show you all these commands, both from within `tmux` as before.

The history of a session is only committed to the `.bash_history` file once you exit a session. When you start a new session, `.bash_history` is read and the command will be available. The reason it works like this is that it allows to evaluate the history of each session separately.

It is possible to configure your terminal to immediately have issued commands available in the history of all sessions.

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows):

> Add the following to your ~/.bashrc:

```
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups # Ubuntu default is ignoreboth
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend  # In Ubuntu this is already set by default

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Learn more about the HISTCONTROL variable [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15926/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entries-in-bash-history).

In a default Ubuntu install, in fact this command alone will do fine:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

Note that any new command from a different session will be available in your session after you "refreshed" the prompt: the history is updated as soon as a prompt is created.